# Verb meaning "to partially hide"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Example:

> We sipped our tea in silence for a while, the steam [...] our faces.

I searched on Google and Thesaurus but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I would say "obscured" or "obscuring", depending on how you punctuate.

Comment: Good luck on picking which answer is "the right one".

Comment: You could use **obfuscate** in the old sense http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&resource=Webster%27s&word=obfuscate&quicksearch=on&sourceid=Mozilla-search but that would likely jst confuse people.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Obscuring** -- Obscure: indistinct to the sight... [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obscure).

Or how about **misting** -- this would imply the feeling of steam condensing on your faces  as well.

Answer (score 16):

I would suggest using a figurative, '**veil**' verb, unless you want a literal word.

**Example** from "Rise and Shine" by Anna Quindlen on [Google Books](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=jSK70MJ2PCoC&pg=PA202&lpg=PA202&dq=%22steam%20veiled%20our%20faces%22&source=bl&ots=IdES2z9K2J&sig=1AJU0Vttkm-2fLqP0lydkCVXe2s&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q7YzVYaCDYTSyAOZxoGwAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22steam%20veiled%20our%20faces%22&f=false)

> The coffee was strong, and the steam veiled our faces as we bent over
>   it.

**Veil** on [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/veil)

> v. veiled, veil·ing, veils v.tr.
>
> 1. To cover with or as if with a veil: *Dense fog veiled the bridge.*
> 2. To conceal or disguise: *a smile that veiled his anger*.

Comment: Ha, I thought about that one, too.

Comment: janoChen - yes, because it is frequently used, it comes first when we think about a hot drink and steam.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the verb ***cloud*** figuratively. In your example, steam acts like a little cloud that partially hides their faces.

> to envelop or hide with or as if with a cloud [[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cloud)

Here is an example from Annie Murray's *The Orphan of Angel Street* (2011):

> Mercy looked over at him from where she was swirling cold water in with the hot, her sleeves rolled up and **steam clouding her face.**

I could even find a very similar example to yours:

> I remember sharing thick slices of homemade banana bread, sitting opposite each other at the kitchen table, **steam from the hot tea clouding our faces**, while I interviewed her for a school project.
>
> [[fromriversedge.net]](http://fromriversedge.net/2012/10/31/october-cooking-club-zucchini-slice/)

Comment: Although beware confusion with the phrase *(someone's) [face clouded over](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/cloud-over)*, meaning they suddenly looked unhappy or worried.

Answer (score 7):

"while the steam **blurred** our faces..."  or "while our faces **were blurred** in the steam."

> blur - "to make dim, indistinct, or vague in outline or character" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blur)
>
> - The tears in my eyes blurred the words on the page.
> - His novel is based on historical occurrences but it blurs the line between fact and fiction.

Comment: Funny, that was the first word I thought of.

Comment: and so did I. +1

Answer (score 6):

I am inclined towards 'shrouding'. It even alliterates with the previous word, adding to the sentence's elegance.

Answer (score 3):

There are any number of good answers, many of them figurative, and the best choice may very well depend on the context or atmosphere you are trying to describe.

For example, if this tea sipping is somewhat somber in nature (perhaps contemplating endings in silence with each other), one might use **shroud**, which both literally means "partially obscure" and also has a somewhat somber connotation due to the [funereal use of the noun form of the word](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/shroud).

If one is going for a more sensual tone (e.g. this is a couple who are romantically inclined), the steam may **caress** their faces, which would imply the partial obscuration but obviously has sensual overtones.

If one is going for a more pensive mood, one might use the fairly connotation-neutral word **obscure** (as mentioned above).

For a more mysterious feel (e.g., you are having tea with a person you do not know who has an intriguing proposition for you), you can use **veil**, which has connotations of hiding an intent or meaning, or at least withdrawal and separation.

Most of your word choices in this area are likely to carry a connotation of some kind, so you may want to ensure that the connotation at least fits the mood you're building - or if not, then to find one as neutral as possible.

Comment: I like this one the best. "We sat and sipped, faces shrouded in steaming vapours of the orient - a piquant, refreshing mist; neither so potent nor so damning as the swirling gloom of the opium dens that capture the hearts and minds of so many visiting that far land. Tea is a queen among spices..."

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about :

> We sipped our tea in silence for a while, the steam **concealing** our faces.

From [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/conceal) :

> **con•ceal** */kənˈsil/* v. [~ + object]
>
> > -
> >     to hide;
> >
> > > cover or keep from sight: *A high wall concealed the house.*
> >
> > -
> >     to keep secret;
> >
> > > avoid disclosing: *to conceal one's true motives.*

And from [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conceal) :

> (transitive) To hide something from view or from public knowledge, to try to keep something secret.
>
> > *He tried to conceal the truth about his health.*

Answer (score 1):

**Occlude** or **occult** are correct words with this meaning.  They are often used in constructions to do with solar and lunar eclipses.  In your context, they'd be a bit odd.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion:

> "screen"

Meaning(v): Protect, hide, or conceal.

> We sipped our tea in silence for a while, the steam **screening** our faces.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are good an,d in particular, technically correct, another word you might consider is **eclipse**.

Definition:

> an obscuring of the light from one celestial body by the passage of another between it and the observer or between it and its source of illumination

While your faces may not strictly speaking be celestial bodies, it is entirely usable in this context, and is nicely metaphorical.

`... while the steam eclipsed our faces` will be understood by any native english speaker (as **obfuscate** or **occlude** probably will not), and it gives the whole scene a slightly eerie feeling, an impression of gathering gloom. Depends on whether that's the feeling you are trying to invoke, it may or may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

From Merriam Websters, Camouflage

:a way of hiding something (such as military equipment) by painting it or covering it with leaves or branches to make it harder to see

: the green and brown clothing that soldiers and hunters wear to make them harder to see

: something (such as color or shape) that protects an animal from attack by making the animal difficult to see in the area around it

All senses are inherently partial concealment and English speakers consistently use and understand that partial concealment is implicit. It does not capture the idea of 75% of the sun was occluded by the moon, rather that the who is hidden, but imperfectly.